# Question about RAID controller compatibility

Tags: 16.04, raid, compatibility

I have a small office server that I use with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried using the fakeraid on the motherboard but it only gives me about 750 GB total space and I have 2x3TB drives. My idea is to configure them using RAID1 but of course I would need a RAID controller to exploit the benefits. The thing is that I haven't seen a regular-priced RAID card that shows Linux compatibility (Ubuntu certified RAID cards section). ($50-$80 USD range)

I kinda like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EA0WMOS) for its specs and features and it seems to have good reviews. There's a person mentioning that it's compatible with 12.04 so my best guess is it should be compatible with 16.04.

The thing is that I can't seem to find info on whether it's compatible or not, whether it would support 2x3TB drives (some cards say they have memory limit).

Has any of you guys tried something similar?

Comment: That sounds promising, any idea about the disk space? I wouldn't want to  buy it and get the same issue with disk space.

Comment: Oh :O where did you see that, I thought I had reviewed the specs :|

Comment: You should post that as an answer :)

Comment: Removed my comments and added it as an answer.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any direct information out there, but from some sites that come up during a Google search of the Marvell 91xx chipset, they are indeed saying that the kernel is compatible with that chipset  https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1614764.html . I took a look at the driver for the UGT-ST644R card, and the driver for that card for Windows shows that it installs the Marvell 91xx driver.

According to the specs on the card, it shows that the drive capacity supports up to 8TB at this time:

http://www.vantecusa.com/en/product/view_detail/578

Also, here is the manual for the card to help familiarize yourself with it:

http://www.vantecusa.com/system/application/media/data_file/ugt-st644r_manual.pdf

Hope this helps!